# How to calculate a scattering matrix numerically for 1D localized potential?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, computational-physics, scattering

I want to calculate a scattering matrix numerically for an arbitrary localized potential for the 1D Schrödinger equation. I want to do this to get a better feel for the scattering matrix.

I can solve for the eigenvectors of such a potential using the following code, which solves a finite square well with a perturbation inside the well. I used hard boundary conditions because I do not know the right boundary conditions for a scattering matrix. I am asking how to solve this conceptually, I am not asking for code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.linalg import eigh_tridiagonal

n = 1000
x = np.linspace(-30, 30, n)
dx = np.diff(x)[0]
U0 = -20
U1 = 100
U = ( (x>=-1)&(x<=1) )*U0 + ( (x>=-.8)&(x<=-.6) )*U1

diag = 2/dx**2 + U
off_diag = -1/dx**2*np.ones(n - 1)
E, psi = eigh_tridiagonal(diag, off_diag)
psi = psi.T
```

Comment: So wouldn't it be easier to just ask about the boundary conditions for the scattering matrix, rather than presenting a largely unrelated chunk of code?